# Undefined method `accept' for nil:NilClass on rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mysql2

Using ruby-1.9.2 and rails 3.2.1. The version of mysql2 is 0.2.7.

Upon running rake db:migrate I get the error:
"undefined method `accept' for nil:NilClass:"

Trace includes:

gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:7:in `to_sql'

Comment: Have you ever done a successful rake db:migrate, or is this a fresh install?  Do any other rake commands work?

Comment: Hi Marc, this is a fresh install - upgrade to 10.7 Mac OS X. Rake db:create worked fine.

Comment: @vectran Did you fix this problem? I am facing same issue now.

Answer (score 28):

Change your `Gemfile` from:

```
gem 'activerecord-mysql2-adapter'
```

to:

```
gem 'mysql2'
```

Comment: why does this happen?

Comment: Still solving problems more than a year later!

Answer (score 11):

Ok, I fixed on my machine. This is because of older MySQL2. Do this to resolve the problem.

```
bundle update mysql2

        Or

bundle update
```

For more details visit [Github](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4632)

Answer (score 10):

For me by removing 
gem 'activerecord-mysql2-adapter'
from Gem File worked out

Comment: Works for me when upgrading from Rails 3.0.3 to Rails 3.2.8

Comment: That medicine cured my ail

Answer (score 1):

Install the lastest mysql2 ruby gem. 
my environtment:

```
Rails3.2.9 + mysql2 0.2.9,  : "undefined method `accept' for nil:NilClass:"
Rails3.2.9 + mysql2 0.3.11, works fine
```

Answer (score 1):

It can happen because of incompatibility of your `mysql` and `ruby` version.

To resolve this either update your mysql gem by `gem install mysql` which will install latest mysql gem.

And then add this in your `Gemfile`.

If still the problem exists then you should see the compatibility between your ruby and mysql

Answer (score 0):

You get this if in your database.yaml file you have:

```
dev:
  adapter: mysql2
```

It should be (even if the gem you are using is mysql2):

```
dev:
  adapter: mysql
```

Took me over a week to figure this out I hope it saves you some time.

Answer (score -1):

Define:

```
def nil.accept
  puts "Accepted."
end
```

And the error will go away.

Comment: hilarious, I hope not too many people will fall into the trap. might not be well received in a Q/A helping site